# Top 3 Max entries for a Combination which a condition

Tags: sql

I am new to sql side. so if this questoin sound very easy then please spare me. I have a 4 coloumns in a sql table.Let say A,B,C,D . For any BC combination I may get any number of rows. I need to get at max 3 rows (which inturn give me 3 unique value of A for that BC ombination) for these selected rows i should have Top 3 Max value of D. As compare to other entries for that BC combination.

So there can be any number of BC combination so the above logic should imply to all of them.

Comment: What the data types of these columns ABCD? and how you would aggregate the BC values for each unique A's values? Can you please add some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support ranking functions.  With these, you can do what you want as follows:

```
select A, B, C, D
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by B, C order by D desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
order by B, C, D desc
```

The row_number() function creates a sequencial number.  This number starts at "1" in very B,C group, and is ordered by the value of D descending.